# Faster way to check if number is divisible with specific number

Tags: c++, division

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long n, k;

    cin >> n >> k;

    int num, count = 0;

    do{
        n--;
        cin >> num;
        if (num > 99 && (num % 10) % k == 0){
            //cout << num << endl;
            count++;
        }
        else if(num < 100 && (num % k) == 0){
            //cout << num << endl;
            count++;
        }
    }while(n);

    cout << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm writing a program to check if a specific number is divisible by specific number inputted by user.

n = amount of numbers inputted
k = the number to check if numbers are divisible

My program works quite good so far, but it exceeds on time limit. Is there any faster algorithm or code than this to check if a number is divisible with another specific number?

Link : http://www.codechef.com/problems/INTEST/

Comment: Why do you do something different for `num > 99`?

Comment: "check if a number is divisible with another specific number?" What's wrong with `num % num2 == 0` ?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I check the last digit only for numbers bigger than 99.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, I am using the % operator in my program, but unfortunately, my program is exceeding the time limit meant for the program.

Comment: @user3002211 please give us more details like actual code. The mod operator is fast in general.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum The actual code is the one I have in the main post. Other than that, I've tried with direct n % k, but it's the same result (time exceeded).

Comment: The slowest bit here is the I/O. What are the values for N  and K? And is this some online programming 'test'?

Comment: The performance of this program is likely to be dominated by the `cin`, not by the `%`...

Comment: How large input values do you have?

Comment: @user3002211 the problem is not with the modulus operator - must be something else in your program and not the code about the divisors.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ n, k <= 10^7. Then the N numbers have value <= 10^9.

Comment: @Roddy Yes, it's an online programming 'test', and the values are n, k <= 10^7. Then the N numbers have value <= 10^9.

Comment: @Roddy Added in the first post.

Comment: "The purpose of this problem is to verify whether the method you are using to read input data is sufficiently fast to handle problems branded with the enormous Input/Output warning". So in other words, you need faster I/O, not a faster divide test.

Comment: So, what do you recommend fo faster I/O? I've checked some of the C++ solutions and they're way too advanced for beginners - http://pastebin.com/cCFFe8EM

Comment: I noticed that your problem specification is different :) @Roddy, yup

Comment: @user3002211 [This one](https://github.com/marioyc/Online-Judge-Solutions/blob/master/SPOJ/Tutorial/450%20-%20Enormous%20Input%20Test.cpp) wasn't advanced at all. I'm guessing it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the problem here is reading numbers from the input in a fast way, not doing the division. With that in mind, here is some code for fast reading:

```
vector<char> buffer(n * 10); // allocate a large buffer
cin.read(&buffer[0], buffer.size()); // fill the buffer with chars from input
buffer.resize(cin.gcount()); // cut buffer size to number of chars actually read
...
```

This reads the whole input file (note the buffer size that is limited by each number having less than 10 digits).

Then, convert the sequence of characters into numbers, and check each number for divisibility by `k` (`num % k != 0`, as others have noted). The code for that can be found in the "complex" solution that you posted (it occupies just 1 line of code there).

Comment: +1 for actually correct answer + suggestion on how to solve it.

Comment: This only reads `sizeof(char*)` characters.  Likely no more than 8.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yeah. Will fix.

Answer (score 2):

Modulo operator (%) is what you want.  Example:

```
if (k != 0)
    return n % k == 0;
```

or for the space sticklers:

```
if (k != 0)
    return !(n % k);
```

Modulo returns the remainder of the division between the two numbers, for example 5 % 2 returns 1.  If the remainder is 0, the numbers are divisible (IE 4 % 2 will return 0).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: True, but it's exceeding the time limit for some reason, it's not fast enough?

Comment: Why the if, the else and all the boilerplate? `return n%k == 0`.

Comment: -1 for the ridiculous if (bool_expr) return true else return false

Comment: I was typing quickly, I can make it less obnoxious if you want.

Comment: You were typing quickly so you made it longer, I see.

Comment: and if `k==0` what should the program do ?

Comment: Up to the asker, I'm just showing him what modulo looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this code snippet

```
    cin >> num;
    if (num > 99 && (num % 10) % k == 0){
        //cout << num << endl;
        count++;
    }
    else if(num < 100 && (num % k) == 0){
        //cout << num << endl;
        count++;
    }
```

You could write simply

```
    cin >> num;
    count += num % k == 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for this little twist, I do appreciate it and I'll try to use that in the future. :)

Answer (score 2):

The point of the 'problem' is that the standard I/O libraries for most languages are very general purpose, and therefore may not be the optimal tools for reading or writing data when the format is well defined and performance is critical.

In this case, you're using the library functions to read from IO streams, which are a highly abstracted from the underlying storage system. Typically, the closer you get to the hardware, the faster your code will run.

I'd start by trying to use the C file IO functions like `fopen` and `fread` to read a large chunk of binary data from the file into memory, then process that memory 'in situ' scanning for numbers and counting the correct matches. Loop until theres no more lines to process, and remember it's **much** more efficent to read large blocks of data that small ones.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 
    if ( n % k != 0 )
use,
    int quotient = n/k;
    if( quotient * k == n )

The modulus operator is slower than the second approach. (It took me 4.5 seconds to run the code with modulus operator and 1 second with the second approach)

Comment: Modern compilers are able to optimize that - the % version is actually more optimized with GCC : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5r8vEcWo4

Comment: You are right. I learned it in the years since I wrote that comment. Thanks for pointing this out.. :)